# ifndef include guard in Gnu Make breaks on nested conditional

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, include-guards

I’m trying to implement [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in Gnu Make. In this Makefile, the first inclusion is OK, while the second one fails with an error.

```
ifndef INCLUDED
INCLUDED = 1
$(info Including)

define macro
ifneq ($(1),)
define inner_macro
macro content...
endef
else
define inner_macro
endef
endif
endef

endif
```

The same effect can be simulated by explicitly giving `INCLUDED = 1` before the inclusion, e.g. on command line.

Gnu Make 4.1 under Gentoo says `Makefile:14: *** missing separator.  Stop.`, while Gnu Make 3.81 under Debian Wheezy says `` Makefile:14: *** extraneous `endef'.  Stop. ``. On the first inclusion, they both say:

```
Including
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

If I try `$(eval $(call macro,whatever))` after the first inclusion, it defines `inner_macro` as expected.

I used `make INCLUDED=1` and `make` commands respectively to get the described behavior.

The same happens when I clear the environment and disable built-in rules and variables: `env -i make -rR INCLUDE=1`. When I use `-p` to dump the database, without `INCLUDED=1`, the `macro` is defined as it should be, but with `INCLUDED=1`, empty `inner_macro` is defined. This is consistent across both the versions of Make. This hints me that when the condition is false, Make parses the Makefile differently and thinks the `else` inside `macro`’s definition belongs to the `ifndef`. Other condition types behave all the same.

If I remove both the definitions of `inner_macro`, the problem goes away.

I read the manual pages [`info make conditional\ syntax`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html) and [`info make multi-line`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html#Multi_002dLine) (formerly `defining`), but I found no caveat there and I still think I am doing nothing wrong.

1. Am I correct with my conclusions?
2. Is this a bug in Make, or am I invoking undefined behavior?
3. How should I implement include guards in Gnu Make?

Comment: As a work-around, I moved the definition of `macro` into another file and replaced it with `include that-file.mk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug.  Report it on [Savannah](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=make).

There's something wrong with the tracking of nested define/endef inside a not-taken ifdef/ifndef condition.  If you don't use nested define/endef then it works; for example (obviously you may not be able to do this in your environment):

```
ifndef INCLUDED
INCLUDED = 1
$(info Including)

define macro
ifneq ($(1),)
inner_macro = macro content...
else
inner_macro =
endif
endef

endif
```

Comment: I’ve used your work-around, although it needed some fiddling with special characters. I stored the characters into macros beforehand and used those macros’ expansions. I will look if the bug has been already reported and file it, if it is not. But is has to wait for a week, I’m extremely busy now.

Comment: It should not be necessary to fiddle with special characters due to ifdef/ifndef.  I don't know what special characters you mean or what kind of fiddling you did, so I can't say more than that...

Comment: I used macros for newlines and tabs to be able to replace define with assignment. Without this, I’m not sure if newline can become a part of variable’s value through assignment.

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies - but I worked around this by redefining define: DEFINE = define. Then I use $(DEFINE) and $(ENDEF) instead. That way make doesn't track it at all.